# Preventing a file from deletion and change

Tags: c#, file, locking

I have a text file. I need to the following:
1. Prevent remove a file.
2. Prevent changes to the file.
Even if the program is not running. Is this possible? Maybe through the use of the service?
Users of application can add new data to a file.

General: I need to prevent my file from delete and any changes (outside of my app).
Thanks.

Comment: Won't it be considered a virus? if a program creates a file which no one can delete?

Comment: This is not a programming problem. You don't solve it by writing a program or a Windows Service. Instead, you solve it through the use of Group Policy and other security settings. Windows comes with out-of-the-box support for things like this, far less fragile than anything you could implement yourself. Ask questions about those on [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com/).

Comment: It is not your system, it is someone else's, they decide over their own system. You can only assign ACLs to the file, but the user can always delete it with administrative rights. Why do you need to prevent changes to the file?

Comment: Your question is missing the most important part. Prevent *who* from removing the file? This is a security question, but you've left out the threat and the attacker. Also, remember: your application runs *on behalf* of your user. The user is in charge; the application is their servant, not their master. If your user wants to destroy your file, that's their business; let them. They own the machine, not you.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: there are stored hashes for specific files. Therefore it is necessary to prevent the change of hashes.

Comment: Ok, worst case scenario, what would happen if the file did in fact change?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen:The file will not be found.

Comment: Please try to avoid one-sentence answers like that. Obviously the file I asked what would happen if it were change will still be found, unless the change is that it was deleted. However, if the change is that one of the hashes changes, and thus you won't be able to address a file using a hash, then yes. However, you still can't, and shouldn't, try to prevent modifications to the file. How about just encrypting the contents? That would make it difficult to make a valid change.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Sorry, English is not my native language. About encryption, yes, I thought about it. But more importantly to prevent file deletion.

Answer (score 3):

This would be something you do with file permissions.  Inside of the files security settings, you can set who can delete the file, who can modify the file, etc.  You could have the application elevate its rights to be able to modify the file.

If the application is not running, it cannot protect the file itself.  Running the application as a service would allow it to stay running, which would allow it to perform some protective actions on the file but you would need a second application to interact with the user then and you would also be doing the job of the operating system.  Elevating rights inside of the C# application is much easier than attempting to do what you are doing through code.

Comment: This is only partially true.  Privileged users (Administrators, Super Users) will be able to delete the file regardless of permissions set.  Same issue though if you created a service to ensure that the file was replaced in the event of deletion, privileged users could terminate the service.  There is no fool proof way to do this 100% but if you keep that in mind while designing your solution you can reach a workable compromise.

Comment: And if so: If the program is not running, keep the file in the service, if the program is open, then close the file in the service. I want to say that it is possible to make communication between the program and service?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows RBS to ensure that the file can only be modified or deleted by Administrators and a specific system user which your program creates and can be run in that context.

NEVER block Administrators' access to files; you will catch seven levels of hell from your application's users, who can't remove this one file (and thus can't remove the installation folder) when uninstalling your app.